# how to Search and Group MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

how to Group MongoDB items by `userId` to find duplicates

DB
[image]

expected output
[image]

Comment: Can you share the sample documents as a snippet instead of an image and the expected output documents? Thanks.

Comment: thanck you. i add picture expected output

Comment: `$group`. See this [demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jcZtaaD8Bge). Yet your question is still unclear.

Comment: db.useractives.aggregate([

  "communityId": { $in: [ObjectId("5e6b4df316eb9d5d04b3238a"),ObjectId("5ee9cef0fd40140026453f57"),ObjectId("615bc0d5af776e00239543f3")] },

  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$userId"
    }
  }
])

I still don't quite understand the syntax.

Comment: Okay, for your scenario you need `$match` pipeline. Check this [demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9elqeTUSOWb).